# How to update DOM element when property inside a model changed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

A model has a property called `rectsList` which contains a list of SVG `rect` elements (an arroy of `rect` elements).

All the rects are append into an `svg` element in `didRender` lifecycle hook method (see code below),

```
didRender() {
    let $svg = this.$().find('svg');
    this._clearSvg($svg);
    this._renderSelectedRects($svg); // append all rects in rectsList to svg
},

_renderSelectedRects($svg) {
    const rects = this.get('image.rectsList');
    rects.forEach((rect) => {
        $svg.append(rect);
    });
}
```

**The expect behaviour:**

When the `rectsList` changes, the `recent` inside `svg` is automatically updated.

**The question:**

Where is the best place to re-render all the `rect`s on the DOM based on the current state of `rectsList`.

I have tried to log the state of the current model using `didUpdateAttrs` but when the `rectsList` changes the method is not get triggered.

I am thinking to use the **observer** but I do not have the access to the DOM element inside callback function.

Comment: In observer case, why you don't have access to DOM? You access to DOM everywhere

Comment: I thought I only have access to dome in `didRender` and `didInsertElement` via `this.$()`

Comment: No, you can access to DOM everywhere

Comment: vie `ember.$`? I think I have seen this before

Comment: via `Ember.$` which is jquery alias or `this.$` that has the scope of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render rects based on `rectList` without using observers or if any additional working needed, with using observers.

I provide a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/323c72a6c820698e6169b18de7817484) with both approaches. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Using a each loop in the SVG is a great approach. Thanks